# How can you get all users related to a user ( directly & indirectly )

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I have a problem where i have to get all users related to a user using a custom LDAP property, for now I can achieve this only by using a recursive function with a query that will keep growing with each call, i know this won't scale, is there's any better way to achieve this.

this is the code I use.

```
/*
 * at start accumlatedUsers === usersToBeSearched accumlatedUsers will be
 * updated
 */
public void GetSubordinatesRecurisve(ArrayList<String> usersToBeSearched, ArrayList<String> accumlatedUsers)
        throws NamingException {

    String searchFilter = "(&(ObjectCategory=User)(|";
    for (String user : usersToBeSearched) {
        searchFilter += "(supeirorName=" + user + ")";
    }
    searchFilter += "))";

    SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
    searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ldapContext.search(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);

    ArrayList<String> usersFounded = new ArrayList<String>();
    SearchResult searchResult = null;
    while (results.hasMoreElements()) {
        searchResult = (SearchResult) results.nextElement();
        usersFounded.add((String) searchResult.getAttributes().get("sAMAccountName").get());
    }

    accumlatedUsers.addAll(usersFounded);

    if (usersFounded.size() != 0) {
        this.GetSubordinatesRecurisve(usersFounded, accumlatedUsers);
    }

    return;
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the issue is that the number of users in your query `ldapContext.search` will grow exponentially, so it does not scale at all. For example, the 1st query is for 1 user, the 2nd query for 3 users, the 3rd is for 9 users and so on.

The users related to a single user can be seen as a tree (if no cycles). The most common way to traverse a tree is the deep first search (DFS) or bread first search (BFS) algorithm. If your goal is to find **ALL** the users related to a user then either option is fine.

DFS (or BFS) is more scalable than your solution because it will always query LDAP with 1 user per time.

I cannot test your method but I am showing you how DFS can be implemented:

```java
// ...
accumlatedUsers.addAll(usersFounded);

for(String userFounded : usersFounded){
    if(!visited.contains(userFounded)){
        visited.add(userFounded);
        List<String> singleUserList = new ArrayList<>();
        singleUserList.add(userFounded);
        this.GetSubordinatesRecurisve(singleUserList, accumlatedUsers);
    }
}

return;
```

**Note** the visited list, it is for preventing cycles in your graph of users.

Comment: Thank you, but i think with this i will still have the same issue, for example if i have 10000 related users , then i will have to make 10000 request, is this feasible in any way ?

Comment: 10k requests are not a lot for LDAP, but definitely it can be improved if you think that is the bottleneck. Is LDAP local or remote? How many total users are in LDAP?

Comment: AD is in a different machine within the local environment, about the users i think around ~5000 but i don't know about the future.

Comment: Ok. How often you call GetSubordinatesRecurisve? if it is once per day then it's fine. If it's is often then you can cache the result (since I don't think it changes often). I'd go with a simple solution (DFS) and eventually improve it with caching, rather than over-optimizing now. Please upvote if you think it's useful ;)